# Weight attribute in Magento layered navigation which catalog input type is text field

Tags: magento

Is there any way to display weight attribute in Magento layered navigation for filtering products which catalog Input type is text field  like price attribute ? I know that attributes whose catalog Input type is dropdown or Multiselect are only possible in layered navigation but weight must be a text field instead of drop down right .please reply me......

Thanks & Regards,
kranthi

Comment: I tried to change catalog Input type of weight to price but it showing currency symbol in layered navigation for weight.can anybody help  me to move in  right direction

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create custom product attribute for weight (type = dropdown), and you can create observer on product save to update this new attribute using text weight value.